# UP sync - External content type picker doesn't show content type

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, user-profile, bdc-model

I create simple content type in SPDesigner. After that I gave all privilegies to that content type (in CA->BDCService; for my user account). Also this content type has both necessary (ReadItem and ReadList) methods. 
Problem: 
I can see for example list (with live data) which include this external content type in page preview BUT when I want to create new sync connection for UP sync and I wanna choose BDC entity, external content type picker give me error "External Content Types are not available. contact your system administrator".

Please, any suggestion?

Comment: Does anybody can help?

Comment: What was the resolution to this problem?

Comment: As I can remember I needed to give some rights for my user (this wasn't SPService account) to "User profile service" application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion: There was problem with application definition. For some reason (for now unknown) SPD generated ExtConType which seems good, but it wasn't. I assume that was some problem with identifiers. After I analyze deeper I'll write new info.